# Append values from a python class object to another class object in Python

Tags: python, json, class, append, mapping

I need help with a python code to append values from a python class object to another python object (call it a base object).

Here is the problem statement:

## 1:

I am getting a JSON file as an input.

```
{
  "Name": {
    "Owner": {
          "FirstName": "sample string 1",
          "LastName": "sample string 1",
             }
          }
}
```

## 2:

I use python code to convert it to a python class object.

```
# Read JSON File
with open('../JSONFile.json') as data_file:
    data = json.dumps(data_file.read())

# Functions to load and convert to string
def _json_object_hook(d):
    return namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
def json2obj(data):
    return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)

# Convert JSON to string format
json_str = str(json2obj(data))

# Create a Python Object of the JSON file
json_obj = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('json_obj', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

## 3:

I have created a python class object manually. The idea is if any attribute is missing in the input JSON file, The final output python class object should have all the attributes with missing values if it is missing in the JSON file.

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = Owner()

    def getatt(self):
        return self

class Owner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Title = ""
        self.FirstName = ""
        self.LastName = ""
```

## Problem Statement:

I need help to map/append the JSON object (json_obj) to the 'Name' class object. As the "Title" is missing in the JSON object, it should be available in the final 'Name' class object with a NULL value. Please let me know if it doesn't make sense. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Comment: I thin it would be easier if you set up a dictionary first, check if is complete with all necessary fields and finally create the object from that.

Comment: Thanks Marco, for sharing your inputs. The actual Output object (Name) have around 1100 fields. I am thinking if that will be feasible to create a dictionary with these 1100 fields, and then check for each field in a new input JSON file and include any field with a NULL (in the final output file) value if missing in the input file. Just wondering if there could be a way to map directly two objects, where the fields are automatically set to a NULL (value in the base/output object) if missing in the input object/file. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you say `Name` objects have around 1100 fields, does that mean it can have ~1100 substructures like `Owner` each with their own key-value mappings? How do you know what attributes to add if they are not present, e.g. where did you take the need for "Title" in the owner from? How exactly do you define the term _output object_ here, or in other words, what do you plan to do with these objects later? And if you say NULL, does that mean the actual database-style NULL value or rather Python's functional equivalent `None`?